# Can I sand the disk of my diskbrakes?

Tags: disc-brake

Is it ok to sand it? I would like to remove the excess black scratches that the bad brake pads have probably created on it, together with some black mucus or something.  I am not sure where the black circular marks on the disk come from, and I only have them on the back brake, which is where I had some problems before. But I'd like to clean those black circular scratches. Do you think if I sand the disk, it would still be fine? My bike is precisely this one:

https://www.paulscycles.co.uk/bikes/mountain-bikes/cube-aim-race-hardtail-mountain-bike-2021-blueberrylime__5750

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are your brakes working well despite the black marks? If so don’t touch them. Well working rotors are best left alone. It’s probably road gunk that has been splashed onto the rotor and burned on.

Try cleaning your rotors with isopropyl alcohol or car brake cleaner before resorting to sanding.

After cleaning with one of those solvents you’ll need to bed the brakes in again by braking very strongly several times in a safe location.

If that still doesn’t work to improve your braking then remove the rotors from the wheel. You have Centerlock brakes so will need to use the spline tool.

Sanding the rotors in place is possible but the quality of the job is much reduced almost to the level of don’t bother.

Sand lightly using a sanding block with fine grit paper in circular motion. You don’t need to sand excessively, your goal is to roughen and deglaze the stainless steel.

Once done with sanding, reattach rotors.

Clean with solvent and bed in. You may gain some braking performance, but it’s not guaranteed.

Comment: is it ok if I use 95 (or 98, or 99) percent alcohol? How important is it to use the isopropyl alcohol?

Comment: Should be fine. You just don’t want to use use something that leaves a residue on the disc e.g methylated spirits/thinners

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic 90% or higher is generally preferred, because what water is there will be gone faster and it will generally solvate hydrophobic stuff much better than something like 70%. Isopropyl alcohol is the usual recommendation because it both leaves no residue (very important for this usage) _and_ can typically be easily obtained in a relatively pure form in most parts of the world. Ethanol would work too if you could find some that doesn’t have other stuff in it (remarkably hard to do most places if you don’t have access to a chemistry supply store).

Comment: Brake cleaner can be nasty stuff. Follow the instructions, avoid contact with skin, wear safety glasses and do it outside.